# image is not being displayed in the blade in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, image, local-storage, laravel-blade, laravel-6

i have just moved my laravel project from the c drive to d drive and back to the c drive, now the problem has arises that the image is not being shown, before it was showing the image in my project.Now the image is being moved to the file system and image name to the database and is not being displayed
i have also linked the storage via `php artisan storage:link`

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Permissions? Does the variable contain anything? Does the image exist? And please don't post code as images but as text

Comment: Which file system used?

Comment: Hello Laxman, could you please provide some more information about your problem? Such a operating system, etc. and a more detailed question please? Your question seems to be lacking information about what you have done

Comment: Just fyi: `width="120px",height="120px"` is not valid. And how is this related to `local-storage`?